# Hooking a javascript function to every postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is some Javascript added on an `.aspx` page:

```
<Head>
<script>
function SayHello()
{
    alert('Hello');
}
</script>
```

and here is how I am calling it from code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),"script","SayHello()",true); 
}
```

The problem is that the Javascript function is called only one time, on the very first page load. I want it to be called on every post back. for example on every button click

Comment: what do you mean by every button click....

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of the Button control and use that on your pages. It has the **OnClientClick** property which you can already preset in your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a pure JavaScript method, such as adding the call to the Javascript function in the body `onload` event:

```
<body onload="sayHello();">
```

Or using the jQuery library to hook onto the document's onready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() { sayHello(); });
```

Comment: Although I agree with the javascript suggestion, you are incorrect about the asp.net lifecycle. Page_Init Event is triggered on every postback.

Comment: @hofnarwillie You're totally right! Not sure where I picked up that misconception. I fixed the answer; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **onload** event:

```
<body onload="SayHello()">

</body>
```

...

If you are using UpdatePanel (AJAX), then you should register script like this:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "key", "SayHello()", true);
```